# How to generate a random variable $r_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n |\frac{r_i}{\sigma_i}|^2\leq\chi^2_{n,\alpha}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

How can I generate $r_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n |\frac{r_i}{\sigma_i}|^2\leq\chi^2_{n,\alpha}$, where  $\sigma_i^2$ is the variance of $r_i$ and, $\chi^2_{n,\alpha}$ is a chi-squared value for $n$ degree of freedom and an $\alpha$ confidence level.

**Edit:** $r_i$ follows a bounded distribution. The given condition is true for all $N$. All parameters are known, except $r_i$ which needs to be determined.

Comment: I don't think that you have uniquely specified $r_i$ at all. Also, should this be true for all $n$ up to some $N$ or just for the final value of $n$?

Comment: right, lets assume that $r_i$ follows a normal distribution. This is the only given knowledge that I have.

Comment: Then that can't possibly work, sometimes $N^2/\sigma^2$ is huge for $N$ normally distributed. To *ensure* this you would need to have a bounded distribution.

Comment: That's right, could you please explain more in details, with a correct assumption. The condition should be true for all $N$. All parameters are known, except $r_i$

Comment: You mean that $\frac{r_1^2}{\sigma_1^2} \leq \chi^2_{1,\alpha},\frac{r_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{r_2^2}{\sigma_2^2} \leq \chi^2_{2,\alpha}$, etc. up to $n$?

Comment: In that case it seems like this might again not be possible depending on what $\alpha$ is. I think the best possible bound on $\frac{\max |X|}{\operatorname{Std}(X)}$ is $1/\sqrt{3}$, which is attained for the uniform distribution on $[-a,a]$.

Comment: Yes Ian. $N$ is known and I don't need to check the condition for smaller than $ N$.

Comment: ...Then it sounds like the answer is actually "no", you merely want the *final* sum to satisfy the property. Well as I said, I think the best bound that can be obtained with probability $1$ is that your sum is less than $n/3$.

Comment: Could you give an answer so that I can credit your thought (give up vote) . I would appreciate it if you could prove your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: I revised my idea (I made a simple error earlier) and provided a proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41931/discussion-between-jolfaei-and-ian).

Answer (score 2):

So we want this inequality to hold with probability 1. I claim that the best possible distribution for the job is the uniform distribution on $\{ -a,a \}$ for whatever $a>0$ you want (the scale factor is canceled by the ratio, so take $a=1$ for convenience). The variance of this is $a^2$ and the maximum value is $a$ so the ratio is $1$.

So in this example, we get that the sum is bounded by $n$ with probability $1$. We cannot do any better if we require the bound to hold with probability 1. Why?  First of all it is clear that sending the mean to zero improves the ratio. Secondly, in order to have $X^2$ be sometimes less than $E[X^2]$ it also must sometimes be more than $E[X^2]$, and this scenario of it being more would impede our bound. Thus the best situation is to have a mean zero distribution such that $X^2$ is always equal to $E[X^2]$, and these are the only way to do it.

So the best bound on the sum that can be achieved with probability $1$ is $n$. I think this means that the desired bound can be obtained for sufficiently small $\alpha$.

Note that this is the best you can do *if* you want the bound to hold with probability 1. You can do many other things if you allow the bound to hold in a different sense, such as with probability at least 0.95 or something.

Comment: I'll have to think about it. At first reading, this seems a better idea than my Comment. Anyhow (+1).

Comment: @Ian, Why is the best distribution a uniform distribution? Previously I was thinking that this problem might be a normal to chi-square transformation problem. lets say that $| \frac{r_i}{\sigma_i} |^2 $ is a member of random variable $ X $ and $ x_i = \frac{r_i}{\sigma_i} $. Now if the values of $\chi^2$ distribution are fixed at an $n$, then we can actually use a gamma distribution to find $r_i$ values.

Comment: @Jolfaei The distribution that ensures that $\sup_{\omega \in \Omega} \frac{X(\omega)^2}{\sigma^2}$ is the smallest is the uniform distribution on two points which are equidistant from zero. The first point is that if the mean is nonzero, then you have made $X^2$ bigger some of the time without changing $\sigma$, relative to the same distribution translated to have mean zero. The second point is that among mean zero distributions, the best thing you can do is to have $X^2=E[X^2]$ with probability $1$, which happens exactly when $X^2$ is constant.

Comment: (Cont.)  I assume here that your $\chi^2$ values are just the critical values, so they are constants, not random variables.

Comment: @Jolfaei I agree with BruceET that my interpretation of the problem seems weird. Is there any more context you can supply?

Comment: @Ian lets continue at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41931/discussion-between-jolfaei-and-ian

Answer (score 1):

Comment.

Something seems missing here. I think this may have something
to do with a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test under the null
hypothesis.

Suppose $X_i$ are iid $Pois(\lambda)$ and $r_i = X_i - \lambda.$
Then $Var(r_i) = \lambda.$ The GOF statistic for observed counts
$X_i$ in  $n$ cells is
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i - \lambda)^2}{\lambda} =  
\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i/\sigma)^2.$$
Also,  $Q \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} Chisq(n-1),$ so *most of the time*
$Q$ will be smaller than, say, the 95% quantile of $Chisq(n).$

Then it would  'almost' work to generate the $X_i$ as $Pois(\lambda).$

I know this is not exactly what was asked, but there are enough
similarities  with a GOF test, that I thought it worthwhile
to mention the connection. Maybe this will help to reformulate the question to something that makes more sense.